# How to use html form time input in Javascript local storage?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get time input in local storage but couldn't succeed it so far.

html part of the time input field of the form:

```
<label for="time"><p>Start</p></label>
        <input type="time" id="time" name="time" min="09:00" max="17:00"/>
```

javascript:

```
function getTime(){
    globalTime = document.getElementById("time").value;
    localStorage.setItem("timeData", globalTime);
}

function inputTime(){
    var newTime = localStorage.getItem("timeData");
    alert(newTime);
}
```

When I call the inputTime function, I get empty alert box, which means I can't get the time input. 
I'd be grateful if you could tell me what is the reason and how can I fix it.

Comment: `#time` does not have a `.value` set. Are you trying to set `localStorage` when users selects a time at `#time` element?

Comment: Works just fine for me, assuming you actually capture the value after it's changed -> https://jsfiddle.net/s1hpvj22/

Comment: @adeneo Note, Question does not include `jquery` tag.

Comment: @guest271314 - I know, I just used jQuery to bind the event handlers easily, the functions are all from the question

Comment: It sets localStorage just fine for me ?

Comment: @guest271314, yes I'm trying to set localStorage when users selects a time at #time element. I'm trying to implement this in pure Javascript

Comment: @adeneo Probably settings have implemented at browser, here.

Comment: @ricster You can use `.addEventListener` to attach `change` or `input` event at `#time` element, to set `localStorage` when user selects a time from the `<input>` element, using same pattern at jsfiddle.

Comment: Where do you call getTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.addEventListener()` to attach `input` event to `#time` element. Attach `click` event to `<button>` elements to set and get value of `localStorage`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="time">
    <p>Start</p>
  </label>
  <input type="time" id="time" name="time" min="09:00" max="17:00" value=""/>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button id="setTime">
    Set time
  </button>
  <button id="test">
    Get time
  </button>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('time').addEventListener('input', getTime);
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', inputTime);
    document.getElementById('setTime').addEventListener('click', setTime)
    var globalTime;

    function getTime() {
      globalTime = document.getElementById("time").value;
      console.log(globalTime)
    }

    function setTime() {
      localStorage.setItem("timeData", globalTime);
    }

    function inputTime() {
      var newTime = localStorage.getItem("timeData");
      alert(newTime);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/AzbVoqkGQwLXGlRV9CQd?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been really helpful.

Comment: Based on pattern which @adeneo composed at https://jsfiddle.net/s1hpvj22/